# How do I perform a complex custom sort in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, sorting

I have an array that looks like the following:

```
[
  { type: 'A', price: '0.01' },
  { type: 'B', price: '4.23' },
  { type: 'D', price: '2.29' },
  { type: 'B', price: '3.38' },
  { type: 'C', price: '1.15' }
]
```

I need to group these by `type` and then sort them by ascending `price`. I can half solve this problem by doing the following:

```
boards.sort_by {|e| [e['type'], e['price'].to_f]}
```

Unfortunately, this sorts the `type`s alphabetically when they should be sorted `BADC`

How do I sort the array by the pre-determined rules?

Comment: the question is not clear: what is the desired output? for products of the same type get the one with the lowest price? and then always order by PRICE ASC?

Comment: I think he wants to sort by type, and where type is equal, he wants to then sort by price.

Comment: @sheldonh. but's that exactly what his code does. Then he says the output should be ordered "BADC" which makes no sense (there's no price nor type order there...) but in any case it seems that type B has been grouped, so he really wants some grouping. Who knows...

Comment: For a start, his code expects string keys where it should expect symbols.

Comment: @tokland, sorry for the confusion. I was having difficulty communicating my problem. steenslag's solution below is what I was looking for.

Comment: @sheldonh, the keys are strings because they are coming to me from an external feed as strings

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
ar=[
  { type: 'A', price: '0.01' },
  { type: 'B', price: '4.23' },
  { type: 'D', price: '2.29' },
  { type: 'B', price: '3.38' },
  { type: 'C', price: '1.15' }
]

SORT_ORDER = 'BADC' #could also be an array, eg ["monday", "tuesday", ...]
p ar.sort_by{|e| [SORT_ORDER.index(e[:type]), e[:price].to_f]}
```

Output:

```
[{:type=>"B", :price=>"3.38"},
 {:type=>"B", :price=>"4.23"},
 {:type=>"A", :price=>"0.01"},
 {:type=>"D", :price=>"2.29"},
 {:type=>"C", :price=>"1.15"}]
```

Comment: I think that by "BADC" the OP means the expected output, not that this he knows it in advance. But the question is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

[edit] The question is not clear. That's what I understand: order boards by `price ASC` but for boards of the same type, get only the cheapest. Using Facets' abstraction [Enumerable#uniq_by](http://rubydoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/master/Enumerable#uniq_by-instance_method) (also in ActiveSupport: [Array#uniq_by](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/uniq_by)):

```
require 'facets'
boards.sort_by { |b| p[:price].to_f }.uniq_by { |b| b[:type] }
```

Output:

```
[{:type=>"A", :price=>"0.01"},
 {:type=>"C", :price=>"1.15"},
 {:type=>"D", :price=>"2.29"},
 {:type=>"B", :price=>"3.38"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your use of the term "group by" is confusing people.

If you want to sort by type, and if type is equal then sort by price, you can do this:

```
boards.sort do |a, b|
  type_order = a[:type] <=> b[:type]
  if type_order != 0
    type_order
  else
    a[:price] <=> b[:price]
  end
end
```

If not, you'll need to better explain what you want. :-)